# submit JSON through form submit via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am trying to submit form through Jquery in MVC. If I remove form element, submit works. what is wrong with my code?

```
<form id="Send" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <button type="button"  id="test" />
    </fieldset>    
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = {........}

    $(function () {
        $("#test").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:0000/api/test",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Presumably somehow the default submit action of the form is triggered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your page, for some reason not shown in your code, is probably behaving like it would when any form is submitting (by `GET`ting or `POST`ing to its `action` attribute). You can, however, prevent this behavior. First, I would do your work when the form itself submits, not in a button click event. This will require two changes. (1): Change your button back to `type="submit"`:

```
<button type="submit" id="test" />
```

And (2): Handle the "submit" event of the form instead of the "click" event of the button:

```
    $("#Send").submit(function(e) {
        // here's where you stop the default submit action of the form
        e.preventDefault();
        // Now execute your AJAX
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:0000/api/test",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }).done(function(response) {
            // handle a successful response
        }).fail(function(xhr, status, message) {
            // handle a failure response
        });
    });
```

Advantages of this approach:

1. You correctly handle the submission process no matter how it was initiated (enter button, button click, programmatically, etc.
2. You don't have to care what your button is called
3. The logic would be bound to an event that you would expect it to be

Comment: *"because you aren't preventing the default action the browser takes when a form is submitted"* The button appears to be a "dummy" button, so it should not submit the form anyway. I also think that the form is submitted *somehow*, but the OP's code doesn't show how/why.

Comment: @FelixKling: I definitely agree with you there. I'll change my wording  a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Use serialize() on the form like:

```
var data = $("#Send").serialize();
```

**Edit:**

Or, if you're absolutely sure you have a server side script that would handle **RAW POST** you could turn your form data into object and stringify that instead, like:

```
var data = {
    'input_1': $("#Send_input_1").value(),
    'input_2': $("#Send_input_2").value(),
    ...
    'input_N': $("#Send_input_N").value()
};
data = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: That doesn't generate JSON.

Comment: @FelixKling - JSON.stringify() does not generate JSON either. It is string what you need to post. With the first variant you'l have the variables readily parsed on the server side. With the second variant you'll have raw posted data that may be a challenge to parse.

Comment: [Of course `JSON.stringify()` generates JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). JSON is a textual, language-independent data exchange format. `JSON.stringify()` returns a string containing JSON. What else should it return?

Comment: @FelixKling: exactly what I've been pointing out - it returns a String and not a JSON Object. Keep in mind that **dataType** is what you expect from server, and not what you're sending to it. Cheers :)

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). It seems you are confusing JavaScript objects with JSON. You are right, `dataType` describes the response format, but `contentType` describes the format of the data in the *request*, and that is set to `'application/json; charset=utf-8'`.

Comment: @FelixKling - well, it seems you know what you're doing. Have you tried my second piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the default form submission, otherwise the browser will do a POST request to the current url with the form data.

```
$('#Send').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents the default submission
    $.ajax(/* ... */);
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to remove the form tags change the button tag for an anchor  with the looks of a button (css) and bind the click event:

```
<a id = "test" href = "#">test</a>
```